# can not call method POST in angularjs

Tags: forms, angularjs, post, form-submit

I do not know why I always get this `Error: Cannot call method 'post' of undefined` when I press submit, please help

Html:

```
<div data-ng-controller="HeaderController">
 <form ng-submit="findFriend()"> 
                    <input type="email" ng-model="friendEmail">
                    <input type="submit" value="Find">

 </form>
</div>
```

Script:

```
angular.module('mean.system').controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', 'Global', '$http', function ($scope, Global, $timeout, $http) {

    $scope.findFriend = function() {
        $scope.email = this.friendEmail;
        console.log($scope.email)
        $http.post('/findfriend', $scope.email).success(function(data) {
            $location.path('/findfriendresult');
        })
    }

}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your parameter count in controller declaration

`angular.module('mean.system').controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', 'Global','$timeout', '$http', function ($scope, Global, $timeout, $http) {`

missing `'$timeout'`